# is this function an ill-shape convex function?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

I have a function with parameter $\vec{{\alpha}}$ where  it is formulated by the formula:
$$
f(D|\alpha)=n_1{\alpha}_{1}+...+n_m \alpha_m -Nlog \sum_{i=1:m} exp(\alpha_{i}+g_i(D)) 
$$
where $g_i{(D)}$ and $N=n_1+...+n_m$ are the (positive) observed value and we want to find optimum value of $\alpha$. It can be shown that the above function is (non-strictly) convex function e.g. if $\alpha=(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_m)$ be the optimum value then $\alpha=(\alpha_1+C, ..., \alpha_m+C)$ is optimum too, for any C.
My problem is that any hessian free optimization method like steepest descent and LBFGS takes a lot of time to do the optimization and actually I need to limit the maximum number of iterations to get an answer which is not a very good one.also for some (far)initial values it freezes in line-search step. 
I really would be appreciated if some one provide me description of shape of my function and the source of them problem and how I can solve it.

Edit: this is an example of steepest descent algorithm with line search  for 30 iterations. the first column is grad. norm and the second column is function value. as you see norm value decreases very slowly.

[image]

Comment: I have deleted the old question because I think that this question(new one) makes sense better

Comment: What is the sum over? Do you mean $\log\sum_i\exp\alpha_i$ instead? // Also if $D$ and $n_i$ are constant then the whole $N\exp(\cdots)$ thing is just a constant factor.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i edit the question to be more obvious(it has a little typo also). also yes, all things except the alphas are simple constants

Comment: So the problem is your numerical algorithm isn't performing as well as you expected it to? What reason do you have to expect better performance? Heck 30 iterations isn't bad at all for a gradient algorithm, and it looks like it converged to a good function value well before that.